# PencilBlue adding new field to the sign up form

Tags: node.js, pencilblue

I'm trying to add a user role field into the sign up form in my PencilBlue site. Created my own plugin, copied `\controllers\actions\user\sign_up.js` and set the `getRoutes`.

Now I'm getting this error: `Cannot set property 'position' of null.` I did all that is needed for creating a new plugin. It all works fine when the core `sign-up.js` file is edited with

```
var user_type = post.admin['id'];
        if(user_type == 0){
            post.admin      = pb.SecurityService.ACCESS_USER;
        } else {
            post.admin      = pb.SecurityService.ACCESS_WRITER;
        }
```

I'm getting an error when used it in my plugin. I set the getRoutes like this

```
SignUp.getRoutes = function(cb) {
        var routes = [
            {
                method: 'post',
                path: '/actions/user/sign_up',
                auth_required: false,
                content_type: 'application/json'
            }
        ];
        cb(null, routes);
    };
```

The template `HTML` file is passing the post values just fine. The structure of my plugin controller directory is flat, so no subdirectories that follows the core set up, exactly how advised by PB team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following this [thread](https://github.com/pencilblue/pencilblue/issues/404), please add

```
request_body: ['application/json', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'multipart/form-data']
```

inside the `getRoutes`

it will look like this below:

```
SignUp.getRoutes = function(cb) {
        var routes = [
            {
                method: 'post',
                path: '/actions/user/sign_up',
                auth_required: false,
                content_type: 'application/json',
                request_body: ['application/json', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'multipart/form-data']
            }
        ];
        cb(null, routes);
    };
```